# Golang embedding interfaces in struct with private access

Tags: oop, go, design-patterns, dependency-injection, interface

I want to replicate the following Java code in Golang in the most idiomatic way possible:

```java
public class Handler {

    private Storage storage;
    private Mapper mapper;

    public Handler(Storage storage, Mapper mapper) {
        this.storage = storage;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public void handleKey(String k) {
        storage.put(k, mapper.map(k));
    }

}

interface Storage {
    public void put(String k, String v);
    public String get(String k);
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Mapper {
    public String map(String a);
}

private static class InMemoryStorage implements Storage {
    private Map<String, String> table;

    public InMemoryStorage() {
        table = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void put(String k, String v) {
        table.put(k, v);
    }

    public String get(String k) {
        return table.get(k);
    }
}
```

`Handler` class only exposes the method `handleKey`. The behaviour of this class is parametrized by passing different concrete `Storage` and `Mapper` implementations.

After reading [Effective Go - Embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding), I thought this would be a good use of embedding interfaces intro structs. But I can't figure out how to avoid exposing the embedded interfaces' methods to `Handler` users. I can do something like

```golang
type Handler struct {
    store  Storage
    mapper Mapper
}

func (h Handler) Handle(k string) {
    h.store.Put(k, h.mapper.Map(k))
}

type Storage interface {
    Put(k string, v string)
    Get(k string) string
}

type Mapper interface {
    Map(k string) string
}

type inMemoryStorage {
    table map[string]string
}

func NewInMemoryStorage() Storage {
    return &inMemoryStore{table: make(map[string]string)}
}
```

but then I cannot pass concrete implementations to the `Handler` (creating struct literal) because `store` and `mapper` are unexported. And I do not want to create factory methods for each possible combination... Any suggestions?

Comment: `public Handler(Storage storage, Mapper mapper) {` in Go would be `NewHandler(storage Storage, mapper Mapper) *Handler {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not embedded; embedding has a specific meaning in Go, [as outlined in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), and as explained in the Effective Go section you linked to. It refers to unnamed fields, whose fields and methods are accessible implicitly from their containing type. Your fields are named, not embedded.

That said, your two struct fields, `store` and `mapper`, are not exported, so they will not be exposed to any user outside the package in which `Handler` is defined; you seem to already have your desired behavior in that regard.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you would have to "create factory methods for each possible combination" - I don't see any reason that would be necessary. You need only one factory method:

```
func NewHandler(s Storage, m Mapper) Handler {
    return Handler{store: s, mapper: m}
}
```

Which could be used with any combination of implementations of `Storage` and `Mapper` by passing appropriate values to the function.